# Can't send special characters through emails with my python program

Tags: python, email, utf-8, smtp

I'm trying to send emails which gathered some information gained through webscraping, but since I'm French and have to use special characters such as é or è I don't know how to change the charset. I'm also open to suggestions, Thanks.

````
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import smtplib

my_url = "http://www.meteofrance.com/previsions-meteo-france/castres/81100"

#ouvre la page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#lit le code html
page_soup= soup(page_html,"html.parser")

#séléctionne la div avec la météo des plusieurs jours
météo = page_soup.find("div",{"class":"liste-jours"})

météo_jour = météo

#choisi le titre de la bonne liste à sélectionner pour avoir la date du jour, et ce titre contient la météo
ciel = météo_jour.li["title"]
mini = météo_jour.li.find("span",{"class":"min-temp"})
maxi = météo_jour.li.find("span",{"class":"max-temp"})

mini = mini.text
maxi = maxi.text

ciel = ciel.replace("é", "e")
ciel = ciel.replace("É","E")
maxi = str(maxi).replace("°","*")
mini = str(mini).replace("°","*")

with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.ehlo()

    smtp.login("..............","................")

    subject = "meteo"
    body = str(ciel)+", "+"la temperature sera de : "+mini+","+maxi+"."

    msg= f"Subject:{subject}\n\n{body}"

    smtp.sendmail("javis81100@gmail.com", ["..............",".................."], msg)```
````

Answer (score 1):

Just add in you variable msg encode('utf-8') like this :

```
smtp.sendmail("javis81100@gmail.com", ["..............",".................."], msg.encode('utf-8'))
```

Then the email look like this :

```
Éclaircies, la temperature sera de : 14°C Minimale,16°C Maximale.
```